# warning in sort function "argument isn't numeric in sort"

Tags: perl

Following code produce warning - "argument isn't numeric in sort ".

what wrong with my code?
code:

```
my $input_file = 'text.txt';
my (@file_content, @sorted);

open(FD, "<", "$input_file") or die "Could not open file '$input_file' $!";
@file_content = <FD>;
close (FD);

@sorted = sort { $a <=> $b } @file_content;
```

file text.txt contain two strings with digits.

Comment: *There are two strings with digits*, So, either you need to cocatenate those strings or may be split it according to your need to make it numeric.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add example input or we cannot help you.

Comment: Change your assignment to `@file_content = map /\d+/g, <FD>`

Comment: example 7  87  2 68 55 40 92 23 92 75 \n
65 83 47 10 83 46 45 30 43 6 \n
70 79 77 83 95 24 35 74 92 19  \n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sort` is obviously complaining on your file content.

You should try to debug the problem:

```
for my $line (@file_content) {
    print "line: ".$line;
}
```

Check if there's anything except numbers (empty lines, lines with chars, etc.).

If this doesn't help, try to get the warning in context:

```
@sorted = sort {
    print "a: $a";
    print "b: $b";
    $a <=> $b;
} @file_content;
```

This will likely generate a long output, but the `a: ...` and `b: ...` lines just above the warning show the line causing the problem.

Do you really want a numeric sort? A text sort might be the solution:

```
@sorted = sort { $a cmp $b } @file_content;
```

Notice that your way of reading the file includes the final line break (usually `\n`). This won't affect numeric sorting as Perl simply cuts off anything which is no number if the string begins with a number, but might confuse the remaining part of your script. Try `chomp` to get rid of them.

Comment: Thank you Sebastian. I need to read some digits from file, sort it and write to another. chomp doesn't help. If I use text sort, I catched following problem                                                                                  65 83 47 10 83 46 45 30 43 6 
7 87 2 68 55 40 92 23 92 75 
70 79 77 83 95 24 35 74 92 19

Comment: Did you try the `print` within sort to find the reason for the warning? Maybe a leading space on a number?

Comment: out for print a: 65 83 47 10 83 46 45 30 43 6
  b: 7  87  2 68 55 40 92 23 92 75
Argument "7  87  2 68 55 40 92 23 92 75 \n" isn't numeric in numeric comparison (<=>) 
Argument "65 83 47 10 83 46 45 30 43 6 \n" isn't numeric in numeric comparison (<=>)
  a: 7  87  2 68 55 40 92 23 92 75
  b: 70 79 77 83 95 24 35 74 92 19
Argument "70 79 77 83 95 24 35 74 92 19 \n" isn't numeric in numeric comparison (<=>) 
  a: 70 79 77 83 95 24 35 74 92 19
  b: 65 83 47 10 83 46 45 30 43 6

Comment: need to remove white spaces tr/ //ds;, then sort

Comment: Ok if it's working for you, but looks to me like you need to `split /\s+/` your values.

Comment: Dear  Sebastian could you please advice how to do back operation from - tr/ //ds;? - I need to add white spaces for sorted string of digits.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you want. Maybe ask it as a new question including samples before/after?